# Microsoft translator API in java application Class path error

Tags: java, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to make Microsoft translator API in my java (windows form) application. I registered in windows azure market place and I registered my Microsoft Translate application so I have these ClientId and Client Secret keys but still it doesn't work. I can't find what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;
import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Translate.setClientId(/* my Client Id */);
        Translate.setClientSecret(/* my Client Secret */);

        String translatedText = Translate.execute("Bonjour le monde", Language.FRENCH, Language.ENGLISH);

        System.out.println(translatedText);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/memetix/mst/translate/Translate
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have that Microsoft's Translation Library on the [Classpath for Linux/Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html).

If this is a standalone program, you could try out the following command:

`java -classpath "%classpath%;.;<path_to_the_translation_library.jar>" Main`

This `<path_to_the_translation_library.jar>` should be the same Library or JAR you used to compile this `Main` class.

Comment: When i Do this I'm getting this error!!  ' java -classpath "%classpath%;.;microsoft-translator-java-api-0.6.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar" Main .
Error: Could not find or load main class Main'

Comment: That error means the Main class itself is missing on the Classpath. Read the Classpath link pasted above. It drills down on that topic a lot better.

Comment: Actually i tried the above code in Netbeans IDE. But its still showing errors even though all the necessary jar files are present.

Comment: And I forgot to mention that I'm using linux for compiling.

Comment: Modified the Classpath link specific to Linux. All you've to do is take a deep breath, go read the Classpath link and see how it works.

Comment: Yeah. I read those. I have all the necessary jar files in the folder containing the java program. Can you please tell me the reason why this code is nor working in Netbeans IDE even after adding all the jar files into the classpath?

Comment: I'm not a NetBeans user, so I wouldn't be able to tell you why. What I can tell you is newbies like you who don't understand basic stuff like Classpath shouldn't be using an IDE for the development. Why don't you try compiling and running this class from command line or a Terminal and post the results in your question (yes, not in the comments section).